# Price of the product does not change for configurable products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I have configurable products on my site, which consists of simple products with attributes color and Product length.
When i select color and Product length, the price of the product does not change and it still shows the minimal price only.
https://nimb.ws/0X32hd
https://nimb.ws/WYT0ek

The prices are properly set in backend.

In console it is showing this error

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on priceBox prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
at Function.error (jquery.js:259)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (widget.js:186)
at Function.each (jquery.js:376)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:142)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.<computed> [as priceBox] (widget.js:182)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._UpdatePrice (swatch-renderer.js:946)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._UpdatePrice (widget.js:100)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._OnChange (swatch-renderer.js:817)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._OnChange (widget.js:100)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._AmOnChange (swatch-renderer.js:193)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some more information. What version of Magento 2 are you using? Have you recently upgraded? Was this product working correctly before any updates or changes were made?

Comment: I m using 2.3.3 version. This was working fine earlier. I dont know what went wrong

Comment: @paj can u help me in this?